# Node.js and Socket.io how can I emit DOM Object while it seem impossible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, object, socket.io

I have recently started to use Node.js and Socket.io, and I have some problem on "emit" socket function.
here my code :

```
var socket = io.connect(':1337');
function Object(id, urlImg){
        this.id = id;
        this.image = new Image();
        this.image.url = urlImg;
    }

    var myObject = new Object(1, "img/myImg.jpg");

    socket.emit("myEvent", myObject);
```

I have this error from socket.io.js:

```
 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

This code only works if I delete the `new Image()` from the object. So I have try something like:

```
socket.emit("myEvent", new Image());
```

and

```
socket.emit("myEvent", $("#id"));
```

or again

```
socket.emit("", document.getElementById("id"));
```

but I have the same error message. So this problem come if I try to send directly a DOM Object in parameter, or a DOM Object inside my Object Parameter.How can I do for emit a DOM Object ???

Comment: Why can't you just send the image url only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot send a DOM object via a webSocket.  `socket.io` will try to serialize the object into JSON so it can send that JSON and all DOM objects contain circular references which will fail with normal serialization.

What you should do is to grab just the properties you need, send those and then on the receiving end, you can build a DOM object there with the appropriate properties.

In your particular example, it looks like you can just send the `id` and the image `url` and then build a DOM object in some other receiving browser using those properties.

If the important properties to send are in variables named `id` and `urlImg`, then you could do this:

```
socket.emit("myEvent", {id: id, url: urlImg});
```

Comment: Thank you I have do like this and it works great ! I have noticed I can't send object method too, and I don't know why ! I have to re-attribute function to my object when I emit it to an other socket :/. I think it's not possible too ? Thank you :)